# How to display Json Data in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have following JSON Data and I tried to display Json data using PHP but it did not display result. Here is my JSON Data

```
$ads={"ReferenceNo":"KWPOG0QoXU","Message":"SUCCESS","Status":1,"ResponseStatus":200}
```

I tried following code but it did not work.

```
$ads1 = json_decode($ads);

echo $ads1->ReferenceNo;
```

Kindly help me how to display result in PHP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: var_dump($ads1);, it could be an array.

Comment: This is not a proper json.

Comment: if you have proper json use $data = json_decode($ads,true); and than $data['ReferenceNo'];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should parse data as string & then do like this:

```
$json = '{"ReferenceNo":"KWPOG0QoXU","Message":"SUCCESS","Status":1,"ResponseStatus":200}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [ReferenceNo] => KWPOG0QoXU
    [Message] => SUCCESS
    [Status] => 1
    [ResponseStatus] => 200
)
```

To get Data, Code like this:

```
echo $array['ReferenceNo'];
```

Let me know for further help.

Answer (score 1):

For people interested in pulling data from a location, instead of adding the json on the file, use the following;

```
   $json = file_get_contents('MYLOCATION.json');
   $array = json_decode($json, true);
   echo '<pre>'; print_r($array);
```

happy coding :)