# Hi need help, how to get data

Tags: php, arrays, json

; this is what i've tried? for display : ADA/ETH bestAsk":0.000699,"bestBid":0.000607 ?

```
$url = "https://exchange-api.lcx.com/market/tickers";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    $data = $json["data"];
    $bestAsk = $json['bestAsk'];
    $bestBid = $json['bestBid'];

 echo $data;
 echo $bestAsk;
 echo $bestBid;
```

> how to get data?
> ; any ideea?

Comment: Which language is it (add it as a tag)? What is not working?

Comment: php, cant display content from json

Comment: [How to display Json Data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028167/how-to-display-json-data-in-php/34772895)

Comment: @luuk , i want just display PAIRS : bestBid and bestAsk

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
$url = "https://exchange-api.lcx.com/market/tickers";

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$data = $json["data"];

foreach($data as $key => $value ){
    #var_dump($value);
    echo $key." - BESTBID:".$value["bestBid"]."\n";
    echo $key." - BESTASK:".$value["bestAsk"]."\n";
}
```

output:

```
ADA/ETH - BESTBID:0.000607
ADA/ETH - BESTASK:0.000699
ADA/EUR - BESTBID:1.6681
ADA/EUR - BESTASK:2.2
ADA/LCX - BESTBID:28.1101
ADA/LCX - BESTASK:45
AMP/EUR - BESTBID:0.044
AMP/EUR - BESTASK:0.067839
AMP/LCX - BESTBID:0.85
AMP/LCX - BESTASK:1
....
```

Comment: i wish you good luck you save my project! :D

Comment: i`ve try the same code on https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/lcx/tickers ,  echo $key."btc price".$value["btc"] , "eth price".$value["eth"], "usd price".$value["usd"]."\n";
 ... what im doing wrong?

Comment: The output from this 2nd url is different compared to the output of the 1st url. The data is differently formatted.  You will have to do some studying to do on how to get info from  an associative arrays as is returned from the json_decode function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly in my system and the data fetched successfully.
if you want to display JSON in PHP you can use `print_r` statement instead of `echo`:

```
print_r($data);
```

Comment: i need display in php like this : ADA/ETH :0.000607  0.000699 [data: bestAsk ; bestBid]                              print_r($bestAsk );   ??? no work

Answer (score 0):

Your should try this one!

```
$url = "https://exchange-api.lcx.com/market/tickers";

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$data = $json["data"];

foreach($data as $key => $value ){
    #var_dump($value);
    echo $key." - BESTBID:".$value["bestBid"]."\n";
    echo $key." - BESTASK:".$value["bestAsk"]."\n";
}
```